# Concurrent "single-threaded" hadoop executions: where is the bottleneck?

Tags: hadoop, concurrency

I am running a compute-intensive, hadoop-based, map-reduce application. I have configured hadoop to use as few threads as possible, but **multiple** concurrent deployments lead to an increase of the **execution time** of the application.

I cannot find the cause of this increase in execution time, so there must be a bottleneck that I have not discovered and/or a configuration parameter that I have missed.

### Testbed

My testbed consists of 3 Dell PowerEdge R630, each with an [Intel Xeon E5-2630v3](https://ark.intel.com/products/83356/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2630-v3-20M-Cache-2_40-GHz): 8 cores, 2 threads/core. These machines are located in the same `10 Gbps` cluster, interconnected by the same switch. These will be referred to as `M1`, `M2`, `M3`.

### Hadoop Configuration

I am running [`hadoop-1.2.1`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/) on `java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64`. I have configured hadoop to use the smallest possible number of threads. Here is my `mapred-site.xml` configuration:

```
<configuration>
        <property>
                <name>mapred.map.tasks</name>
                <value>1</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum</name>
                <value>1</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>mapred.reduce.tasks</name>
                <value>1</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum</name>
                <value>1</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
                <value>10.0.0.1:9001</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution</name>
                <value>false</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution</name>
                <value>false</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>tasktracker.http.threads</name>
                <value>2</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>mapred.reduce.parallel.copies</name>
                <value>2</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

### Deployment

The actual deployment takes place on containers, spawned via [nova-docker](https://github.com/harnesscloud/nova-docker). In each deployment I am spawning 3 containers, `C1`, `C2` and `C3`, with 1 container per physical machine. Let's assume that `C1` is spawned on `M1`, `C2` on `M2`, `C3` on `M3`.

In particular:

- One container, `C1`, acts as the "Master"; it runs the Namenode and the Jobtracker services.
- The other two containers, `C2` and `C3`, act as the "Slaves", they run the Datanode and the Tasktracker services.

I have run this experiment twice:

- One concurrent deployment
- Two concurrent deployments

"Two concurrent" deployments means that there are two identical deployments, running concurrently. To further clarify, when two deployments are running, there are six containers present:
 - `C1a` and `C1b` on `M1`
 - `C2a` and `C2b` on `M2`
 - `C3a` and `C3b` on `M3`

`C1a`, `C2a` and `C3a` belong to the same map-reduce execution and communicate with each other, as expected. Same goes for the containers `C1b`, `C2b` and `C3b`, respectively.

### Execution time

Both cases (1 concurrent deployment, 2 concurrent deployments), were run 10 times, to get a good sample. Here is the execution time with 1 and 2 concurrent deployments; as it is evident, with 2 concurrent deployments the execution time rises by 6.72%.

[image: MapReduce Execution time]

### Issue

My **question** is: why is the execution time longer when running two concurrent deployments, even though I have configured hadoop to use as few threads as possible? In particular:

1. Could I be PCIe-bottlenecked or CPU-bottlenecked? (see below)
2. Have I missed something else in configuring hadoop to use as few threads as possible?
3. Is hadoop using more threads than the ones I am aware of, that could be congesting the CPU or another resource?

I have already investigated the following:

- Bandwidth consumption: we are definitively not network-bottlenecked. The network can sustain up to 10 Gbps, the application is not consuming more than 400-500 Mbps, on average, and there is nobody else using the cluster.
- PCIe: I have already measured the PCIe bandwidth to investigate whether I am bottlenecked there. I have opened a [related question on Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1217978/do-these-pcie-readings-indicate-a-congested-pcie) to ask whether my readings indicate a congested PCI or not.
- CPU utilization: please see the next section.

### CPU metrics

I installed the [PCM tools](https://github.com/opcm/pcm) to measure the CPU utilization during the executions. These tools were installed on one of the **physical machines** that hosts the slave containers (Datanode, Tasktracker).

I measured the utilization for cores in active state for the following cases:

- Idle (labeled "0 tenants")
- 1 concurrent deployment (labeled "1 tenant")
- 2 concurrent deployments (labeled "2 tenants")

[image: CPU utilization]

As it is evident, the CPU utilization for 1 or 2 concurrent deployments is similar, albeit for 1 deployment is slightly higher on average. Therefore, CPU utilization does not seem to be an issue; what could I be missing?

Please let me know in the comments whether I could provide any additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, the eventual bottleneck is *I/O bandwidth when writing to disk*. With the help of `iotop` I measured the writing speed:

[image]

And with `dd` I measured the maximum writing speed:

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=diskbench bs=1G count=1 conv=fdatasync
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 7.38756 s, 145 MB/s
```

The writing speed seems to be constant around 10 MB/sec, reaching quite often up to 120-160 MB/sec. A natural question would be "*why do we have continuous writing to the disk?*" It's how hadoop works: the mappers are writing their intermediate output to the local disk, but not the HDFS, as it has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23578418/why-map-tasks-outputs-are-written-to-the-local-disk-and-not-to-hdfs).

Therefore, since the mappers write continuously to the local hard disk, a bottleneck is expected there when multiple hadoop executions are run, even if we have CPU processing power to spare.